# How to find the regression line in an interval of time, where there is a linear evolution?

Tags: python, statistics, regression, linear-regression

Here is my code so far. I saw some answers similar, but this is a little different since I don't call my data from the internet and have created a csv file. Is it the same as [How can I draw a linear regression line in this graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995356/how-can-i-draw-a-linear-regression-line-in-this-graph) ?

Thank you in advance.

```
import datetime as dt # library for dates and time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # plots library
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots as stplt
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np
import statistics as ics

plt.close('all')


def parser(x):
    return pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y')
#Read the *.csv file

amazon = pd.read_csv('AMZN.csv', parse_dates=[1], index_col=1, 
                    squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
amazon.Close.plot()

print(amazon.describe())

print(amazon['Volume'].var())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you using linear regression from scikit learn. The code looks kind of like this (its just pseudo code):

```
from sklearn import linear_model

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression() #create a linear regression object

regr.fit(your_x_data, your_y_data) #fit your data (create the linear regression parameters) 

your_y_pred = regr.predict(your_x_data)
 #create your linear function

 plt.plot(your_x_data, your_y_pred , color='blue', linewidth=3) #plot the linear function`
```