# Plotting the R square error for regression model results

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, statistics, regression

I implemented a regression neural network using keras, and I am trying to plot the results.

```
plt.plot(Y_test, Y_pred, 'ro')
plt.xlabel('Actual values')
plt.ylabel('Predicted values')
plt.show()
```

but I need to add the fitting line in my plot as the below image. Could you help with this.

[image: Figure example]]

Comment: Hi Fatima, Pls accept the answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 2):

First generate the regression model with `scipy.stats.linregress`: -

```
import scipy as sp
linreg = sp.stats.linregress(Y_test, Y_pred)
```

The regression line can then be added to your plot: -

```
plt.plot(x, linreg.intercept + linreg.slope*y, 'r')
```

Similarly the r-squared value: -

```
plt.text(0, 1, linreg.rvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Y_test = np.random.rand(100) # Random Data
Y_pred = Y_test + np.random.rand(100)*0.1 # Random Data

r_squared = 0.59
plt.scatter(Y_test,Y_pred)
plt.xlabel('Actual values')
plt.ylabel('Predicted values')

plt.plot(np.unique(Y_test), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(Y_test, Y_pred, 1))(np.unique(Y_test)))

plt.text(0.6, 0.5, 'R-squared = %0.2f' % r_squared)
plt.show()
```

[image: Iamge]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, what I am not able to draw is the r_squared line itself. I already have the r_squared value.

Comment: ** I need to add the R square error in my plot ** Since you have r_squared value already, using this you can draw it on the line itself. Did you try this? And what did you mean by the r_squared line? Is that the regression line you need?

Comment: Yes I mean the regression line, I am not able to add it to the plot. suppose it is 0.59

Comment: Your problem is not clear. I wonder how a line be just a single number like 0.59. You are shuffling the meaning of r-squared and the regression line. Here I have add the R-squared value (0.59) in your graph. But if you further need the line, you will have to plot the regression line first.

Comment: I am implementing a regression neural network and I am new to python, after training my model I got the R square error.   Y_pred=model.predict(X_test)
r2=r2_score(Y_test, Y_pred). I am trying now to plot the predicted and the actual values and the regression line also

Comment: Is there another way to do it. If we have the array of actual values and the array of predicted values, can we write a function to calculate R square and call this function while plotting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995356/how-can-i-draw-a-linear-regression-line-in-this-graph    This link will help you to plot the line.

Comment: @Fathima was my answer helpful to you?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But in my case I have multiple X values in order to predict Y. So I was trying to plot actual Y versus predicted Y, not X versus Y

Comment: Edited the answer according to question editions. I think this is what you looked for. Check it.

Comment: Thanks for the update, what if the number of unique X values is different than the number of unique Y values. I am getting this error : ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (321,) and (6405,)

Comment: You should make x and y numpy arrays, not lists:

x = np.array([0.46,0.59,0.68,...])
y = np.array([0.315,0.383,0.452,...])

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Y_test = np.random.rand(100) # Random Data
Y_pred = Y_test + np.random.rand(100)*0.1 # Random Data

r_squared = 0.59
plt.scatter(Y_test,Y_pred)
plt.xlabel('Actual values')
plt.ylabel('Predicted values')

plt.plot(np.unique(Y_test), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(Y_test, Y_pred, 1)) 
np.unique(Y_test)))

plt.text(0.6, 0.5, 'R\u00B2 = %0.2f' % r_squared)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please explain why this solution works, and why its superior to other answers already posted.